# Static library is fine alone but throws errors when being referred

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, static-libraries

I'm developing a new static library and a Win32 application inside one solution using Visual Studio 2017. The idea is simply that my Win32 project refers to the static library. However, I cannot.

The static library is **fine when being built alone**. But if I build Win32 application project that refers to the lib (or by setting it as Startup project), there are a lot of errors. To list a few: `name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`, `'string': is not a member of 'std'`, `'WRL': a namespace with this name does not exist`... What I understand and guess is that the target project doesn't understand the links of the static library. (Am I wrong?)

The static library itself refers to `std`, `Microsoft::WRL`, and `Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers`...

I have tried to look at the ways to link static libraries (refer lib location, lib file name, header location), and even tried to enable Link Library Dependencies in Librarian > General options of the static library. No use :(

Any other directions that I can look at? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You still need to include headers that define the types in your Win32 application. A C++ static library ``.lib`` only provides the symbols at link time, not at compile time.

Comment: Omg, that's it :D Please convert this to an answer so I can mark it. Basically, the lib refers `wrl.h` and `stdexcept`. I added 2 include lines for those in Win32 project and it runs now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to include headers that define the types in your Win32 application. A C++ static library `.lib` only provides the symbols at link time, not at compile time.

C++ libraries are just collections of `.obj` files. You need to include headers in your application to consume the library. The `.lib` itself just provides the object code needed for the linker, *not* the type definitions for the compiler. This system dates back to the early days of C.

Typically you set up a *public header* for the static library that defines the types and entry-points needed to use it. Then the library itself may have it's own internal headers that it uses when building that are not intended for consumption by 'clients'.

If there is more than one public header, often they are put into a specific directory like `inc` or `include` and then the private headers and all the other source files are put elsewhere like `src` / `source` directory. This organizational trick means that clients of your library will only include the public headers without the chance of them including your private ones because they should only have your public `inc` / `include` folder in their include search paths.

In the *public header*(s) you typically include standard headers that are required for the header itself to compile (i.e. `<vector>`, `<string>`, etc.).

> In Modern C++, best practice is to 'wrap' your types in a C++ namespace which is not that important for small projects or when you are just using static libraries to organize locally, but it becomes important when you want to share your static library for other developers to consume. There's some tricks to using C++ namespaces well, such as avoid having `using namespace` statements in headers, using anonymous namespaces within modules to hide private types, etc. See [this tutorial](https://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-namespaces-and-anonymous-namespaces) for the basics.

See [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2017)

> For some examples of Visual C++ libraries that use the best practices, see DirectX Tool Kit for [DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) / [DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12), [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex), and [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the properties of the win32 application.

The *Include additional folders* in *Configuration properties* -> *C/C++* - > *General* have to show the location of your *h* files.

Comment: Yes, I changed this. Totally there are 3: C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories; Linker > General . Additional Library Directories; Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.

Comment: To find the h file only this setting needs to be completed. Unless you didn't include the static lib in  **Refrences**?

Comment: Hi, please see my comment in the original question for a clearer situation. I solved the problem by including the headers needed in the static library inside the Win32 application. (E.g., static lib include <wrl.h>. My win32 app also needs to include <wrl.h> itself, not just include <my_lib.h> alone.) Thank you anyway :D!